# How to use JavaScript Promise Chains Smartly?

Tags: javascript, promise

How can you skip a step in a promise chain if a certain condition is met, without complicating the code?

```
function fetchData(shouldSkip) {
  fetch('https://api.example.com/step1')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      if (shouldSkip(data)) {
        // Want to jump to final step. How?
      } else {
        return fetch('https://api.example.com/step2').then(response => response.json());
      }
    })
    .then(finalData => {
      // Need to work with finalData here, but what if there's no step2?
    });
}
```

Comment: Do you want to do anything in your final `then` callback when `shouldSkip(data)` is true? Separately: Have you tried [`async` functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)?

Comment: Side note: Nothing in that code handles promise rejection, which will lead to an "unhandled rejection" error if anything goes wrong. Also, if that's the standard `fetch` function, you need to check for HTTP success (check `response.ok`), see [my post](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2018/06/common-fetch-errors.html) on my old anemic blog.

Comment: `return` whatever you want the final step to receive in `if (shouldSkip(data))`…?!

Comment: I see you're relatively new to SO. One of the key ways to make sure you get the best out of the site and your experience here is to not post-and-run. When you post a question (or answer), *stick around* for a few minutes so you can respond to anything that comes up in the comments. SO is a very, very active place.

Comment: `async/await` is your answer

Comment: Promise chain is the callback hell in a different shape. Use [`async/await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) with `try/catch`.

Comment: @axiac What's hellish about promise chains? You have neither unnecessary infinite nesting (indentation), nor required (but easy-to-forget) error handling at each step.